# if I know $f(x+1) = 2f(x) + 1$, how do I solve f(x)

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-equations, recursive-algorithms

This is just my thought on run time of a binary search:
if you are allowed to make 1 comparison, you can search a sorted list of length 1, but if you are allowed to perform 2 comparisons, you can search a list of length 3 (if the list is sorted [1,2,3], you first search the middle [2] and depends on the result, you continue down the left[1]/right[2], which is just a sorted list of length one)

it is pretty obvious that when you are given an extra comparison, the length of the sorted list you can search is doubled + 1

$f(x+1) = 2f(x) + 1$

I want to represent $f(x)$ in terms of x, the relation between list length and number of comparison required.
the answer is $$f(x) = 2^x -1$$ However, I want to solve it using math...but I don't remember how to solve a recursively defined function like this

thanks

Comment: First of all, this isn't the definition of a function, it is the definition of a sequence and it must have a starting point, a base, so to speak.

Comment: @Aleksandar Technically, a sequence is a function. And how do you know he doesn't want it for real $x$, too?

Comment: You  could define $f(x)$ as any  function on $[0,1)$ and get a function on the real line. In particular, then you don't necessarily need $f(0)=0$ for this to be true - indeed $f(x)=C2^x-1$ for any constant $C$ is a solution. You need at least one value for $f$ to determine it on the integers.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews He needs to have a base, $f(x+1)=2f(x)+1$ is actually $f(x)=(c_1+2)2^{x-1}-1$. The question he is asking can only been answered if there is a "base"!

Comment: No reason to shout, @Aleksandar. I know that. That doesn't make your first comment correct.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Also, a sequence isn't a function. A function is putting in an input and getting out an output, a mapping. A sequence is just a list of numbers. Some sequences are functions, not all though. Like ${1,6,7,0,1,2,6,1,2,3,0,1,2,8,10,233}$.

Comment: You are gonna need some more schooling, @Aleksandar. A sequence is a function. I think you are confused about what a function is. Good luck with your continuing education, but please don't confuse people with your misunderstandings.

Comment: Derogatory? I see "you are gonna need more schooling"=you are incompetent. You are right @ThomasAndrews a sequence is a function, but not all things that apply to sequence apply to functions. Sorry for yelling. I confused a set with a sequence.

Comment: You made a mistake. Then, when I pointed it out to you, you *insisted you were correct.* I was a bright kid once, but I had a lot to learn. A careful person would weight the comment, and not jump to repeat a mistake in a defensive fashion. @Aleksandar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29837/discussion-between-aleksandar-and-thomas-andrews).

Comment: Every sequence is a 'special case' of a function, that is, a function $f:\Bbb N \to X$.

Comment: If you fail to specify the domain of a function, you fail to specify the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $g(x)=f(x)+1$. Then
$$
g(x+1)=f(x+1)+1=2f(x)+1+1=2(f(x)+1)=2g(x).
$$
This suggests a representation of the form $g(x)=g(0)2^x$ so that $f(x)=g(x)-1=g(0)2^x-1$.

Conversely, you can check that all $f(x)=c2^x-1$ satisfy your functional equation.

Comment: how do you come up a solution like this? is there are general method to solve this kind of recursively defined function?

Comment: These equations are called functional equations, there are lots of techniques to solve different kinds of equations, and there is a lot of literature about it. You could start by eyeing the wiki page.

Comment: I did a quick look up, since the fibonacci sequence $f(n) = f(n-1)+f(n-2)$ is also qualified as a functional equation, I wonder if there is an algebraic equation that represents it?

Comment: Yes there is! See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsFibonacciNumberFormula.html

Comment: @watashiSHUN Of course; $$f(n) = \frac{\varphi ^ n - (-\varphi) ^ {-n}}{\sqrt 5}$$ where $\varphi$ is the golden ratio $\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt 5}{2}\right)$

Comment: @watashiSHUN Here, you can come up with it by noticing that the operation "double it and add 1" on integers is the same as the operation "append 1 to the binary expansion".

Answer (score 2):

We can use some insight from differential equations (if we're familiar with that).

After subtracting $f(x)$ from both sides the equation becomes

$$
f(x+1) - f(x) = f(x) + 1. \tag{1}
$$

Let

$$
\Delta f(x) = f(x+1) - f(x)
$$

be the discrete derivative, also known as the first forward difference.  Equation $(1)$ becomes

$$
\Delta f = f + 1. \tag{2}
$$

We will first solve the homogeneous equation

$$
\Delta f = f, \tag{3}
$$

then combine combine this with a particular solution of $(2)$ to get the general solution to the equation.

Just as the exponential function $y(x) = e^x$ satisfies $y' = y$, the function $f(x) = 2^x$ satisfies $\Delta f = f$. Thus, the general solution of $(3)$ is

$$
f_\text{hom}(x) = A2^x
$$

for any constant $A$.

It is easy to see that a particular solution of $(2)$ is

$$
f_\text{part}(x) = -1,
$$

so the general solution to $(2)$ is given by

$$
f(x) = f_\text{hom}(x) + f_\text{part}(x) = A2^x - 1.
$$

At the top of your post you specified that

> if you are allowed to make 1 comparison, you can search a sorted list of length 1

and this is equivalent to requiring

$$
1 = f(1) = 2A - 1
$$

and thus $A = 1$.  Finally, the solution to your recurrence is

$$
f(x) = 2^n - 1.
$$

---

**Bonus round.**

Defining the second difference

$$
\Delta^2 f(x) = \Delta(\Delta f(x)) = f(x+2) - 2f(x+1) + f(x),
$$

show that the Fibonacci recurrence

$$
f(x+2) = f(x+1) + f(x)
$$

is equivalent to the second order discrete differential equation

$$
\Delta^2 f + \Delta f - f = 0. \tag{4}
$$

Show also that, if $g(x) = (1+r)^x$, then

$$
\Delta g(x) = r g(x)
$$

and

$$
\Delta^2 g(x) = r^2 g(x).
$$

Use these properties and equation $(4)$ to obtain the expression for the Fibonacci numbers from [Ant's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1461836/if-i-know-fx1-2fx-1-how-do-i-solve-fx#comment2979547_1461886).

*Hint:* If you were trying to solve the ordinary differential equation

$$
y'' + y' - y = 0,
$$

you would substitute $y(x) = e^{rx}$ and solve for $r$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "$2^x$ is a  fixed point "bit?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD, I just mean that the function $h(x) = 2^x$ satisfies $\Delta h = h$ since $$\Delta h(x) = 2^{x+1} - 2^x = 2^x (2-1) = 2^x = h(x).$$ Maybe I'll reword that bit.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose
$f(x+1)
=af(x)+b
$.

We want to "adjust" $f$
so the adjusted function $g$
satisfies
$g(x+1) = ag(x)$,
since we know how to solve this.

The simplest adjustment
is to add a constant
to $f$.
So,
let
$g(x) = f(x)+c$,
where we want to determine $c$
so that
$g$ is "nice".
Then
$f(x) = g(x)-c$,
so
$g(x+1)-c
=a(g(x)-c)+b
=ag(x)-ac+b
$,
or
$g(x+1)
=ag(x)-ac+b+c
=ag(x)-c(a-1)+b
$.

To make this
become nice,
choose $c$
such that
$b-c(a-1) = 0$
or
$c = \frac{b}{a-1}
$.

Then
$g(x+1)
=ag(x)
$,
so
$g(x) = a^x g(0)$
(or $g(x) = a^{x-1}g(1)$),
or
$f(x)+c
=a^x(f(0)+c)
$
(or
$f(x)+c
=a^{x-1}(f(1)+c)
$
)
or
$f(x)
=a^x(f(0)+c)-c
$
(or
$f(x)
=a^{x-1}(f(1)+c)-c
$
).

In your case,
$a=2$ and $b=1$,
so
$c = 1$,
and we get
$f(x)
=2^{x-1}(f(1)+1)-1
=2^{x-1}2-1
=2^{x}-1
$.